# Why special rules for `for` statement scope?

Tags: c++

I stumbled recently in this problem

```
for(int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++) {
   ...
   P2d n = ...   <<<--- error here
}
```

the compiler was complaining about the fact that the `n` local variable has been already defined, despite that the open brace looks like it should start a new scope.

Indeed the standard has a special wording for this and while the code compiled fine with g++4.6.3, it complains with more recent versions and other compilers.

What is the rationale (if there is any) behind this special rule?

To be more clear: the standard explains that this is not permitted and I've no questions about the ***technical*** reason for which that's an error: I was just wondering why the committee decided to use special extra rules instead of just creating another nested scope when seeing the opening brace (like it happens in other places).

For example to make the code legal you can just wrap the body with **two** brace pairs instead of one...

Please also note that braces after `for/while/if`, while considered good practice, **are not mandatory** and not part of the syntax, but still a scope containing the loop variables exists (therefore using function definition as another example where the scope of the locals is the body of the function is not relevant: a function body is not a statement and braces are mandatory).

In the C++ syntax the body of a `for` is just a statement; however if this statement happens to be a braced group then it gets a special handling in `for/while/if` (that doesn't happen when you use a braced group as statement elsewhere in the language).

What is the reason for adding this extra complication to the language? It's apparently not needed and just treating the braces as another inner scope seems (to me) simpler.

Are there use cases in which this simpler and more regular approach doesn't work?

Note that **I'm not asking opinions**. Either you know why the committee took this decision (requiring also a quite elaborate wording in the standard instead of just having the body as a regular statement with the regular handling of a brace enclosed block when used as statement) or you don't.

### EDIT

The "single scope" view for the syntax is for me unnatural but technically possible for the `for` statement that can be rationalized as a single block with a backward `goto` statement, but it's hard to defend in a very similar case for the `if` statement:

```
if (int x = whatever()) {
    int x = 3; // Illegal
} else {
    int x = 4; // Illegal here too
}
```

but this is instead legal

```
if (int x = whatever()) {
    int z = foo();
} else {
    int z = bar();
}
```

So are the condition, the `then` part and the `else` part of an `if` statement the same scope? No because you can declare two `z` variables. Are they separate scopes? No because you cannot declare `x`.

The only rationalization I can see is that the `then` and `else` part are indeed separate scopes, but with the added (strange) rule that the variable declared in the condition cannot be declared in the scope. Why this extra strange limitation rule is present is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Are you basically asking "why aren't there *two* nested scopes here?"

Comment: for(int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++) this is basically loop header and following curly brackets contain what is called body of loop, so both n's are in same scope and conflicting with each other

Comment: Maybe it's not specific to `for`, I can reproduce the error with other constructs like `if` and `while`, see [LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e22d6354114c01d).

Comment: I'm curious to see how many answers are posted by someone who actually *reads the question* (since you clearly acknowledge you're aware it doesn't work, noting the relevant standard content et'al).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: you've one scope already (for example you can put a statement without braces). The question is why not handling braces normally by creating a new scope instead of adding a special rule...

Comment: This is inherited from C, IINM, so maybe you're asking about the wrong standard. It's also not specific to `for`, it's consistent with the rules for scope of function and `if` local variables.

Comment: Why is it this way? Because the alternative would be chaotic.

Comment: @6502: Yup.  The answer is "because the C standard says so"!.  More specifically, it explicitly says that variables declared in `for` are actually in the scope of the entire loop.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: ... that is composed of one statement. If this statement happens to be a braced group however the variables are not in the scope of this statement, but they go INSIDE the braces, because we say so and we like to make special cases for the fun of it...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: what is chaotic about just treating the body as any other statement in the language (i.e. starting a nested scope if it's a braced group)?

Comment: Surely you can see the confusion that would be caused by what you suggest!

Comment: I added the C tag. Not many questions deserve both C and C++ tags, but here it seems appropriate. @OliverCharlesworth's "because C says so" response naturally leads to the question why C does say so.

Comment: I don't see this as a special rule. I would *expect* the scope of variables defined in the control structure to be within the block that the control structure governs. A set of braces on their own are simply missing a control structure. The way things are defined also is consistent with defining functions, where the arguments are local to the function block.

Comment: The rules are only special if you interpret them in a way that makes them look special. See my answer.

Comment: Does no one get it that this is not the question? He wants to know what are the reason behind it."Because it was the best way" isn't a real answer. I want to know (and I guess the OP wants too) WHY times ago inherited from what language ever, they decided to take this as the easy way instead of what the OP stated.

Comment: @6502 - what was the compiler's complaint? Was it an error or a warning? And what compiler was it?

Comment: @Zaibis: I thought I got the point of the question, did you read my comment and answer?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yep I did, and In my point of view, you are absolutly missing the point of his Question. You just explain what he already explained in his question. But you aren't in anyway responding to the background he is asking about. (again said, if I get him right.) And your comment I simply couldn't find.

Comment: @6502 responding to your last edit: If you want it grounded on a wording of the standard, you had to clarif< (even if its not you who inseted that tag, anyway he was right) You want the standard of C or C++? or as it is a backround reason would be a statemant of any of the both satisfy you?

Comment: @Zaibis: I don't think I understand. I didn't repeat anything in his question; I told him why I think it's not actually a special rule in the first place. That's definitely not already in his question. (Also, his newest edit is newer than my answer so I'm hoping you're not referring to that part.)

Comment: @6502: The number of times it's constructed and destroyed is irrelevant to the scope. For example if you have `int x = 5; static Type obj = Type();` inside a loop, they both have the same scope but only one of them is created/destroyed multiple times.

Comment: Some earlier versions of `C` allowed `for (int i=0; ...) { } foo(i)`. This allowed the declaration of `i` to occur "before the for" as if `int i; for(i=0; ...) { } foo(i)`.  Then `i` had a lifetime that continued onward and the following would be a problem: `for(int i=0; ...) { } for(int i=0; ...) { }`.  So unless one considers 3 levels (before `for()`, in `for()`, in `for()` body), and stays with only 2: the declaration of `i` in `for (int i=0; ...) { }` will be 1) before the `for()` loop and it's lifetime continues after the loop or 2) local to the `for()` loop.

Answer (score 19):

```
int i = 0;
for (MyObject o1; i<10; i++) {
   MyObject o2;
}
```

Can be translated from the point view of recent compilers into:

```
int i = 0;
{
    MyObject o1;
    Label0:
    MyObject o2; //o2 will be destroyed and reconstructed 10 times, while being with the same scope as o1
    i++;
    if (i < 10)
        goto Label0;
}
```

This is the answer to your last question mark at the end, they didn't add something complicated, just used goto to label in the same scope, and not goto to out of the scope and then enter to it again. I don't see clear reason why it's better. (While it will do some incompatibility with older codes)

Comment: +1: True. I didn't know jumping backward before an object definition was legal. I removed the example because it's indeed irrelevant (can be seen as a single scope with a goto). Why not simply saying the body i s a statement (with possibily a nested scope if you use braces) is a question still to be answered IMO.

Comment: @6502 Then this answer now is irrelevant? (Whatever to delete it or not)

Comment: I think it's ok. It's just showing that the single-scope view is not impossible (it's just, in my opinion, more complex).

Comment: @6502 OK, if I will find some source why they changed it I will put an edit at the end of this post.

Answer (score 18):

The semantics are not special for the `for` loop! `if (bool b = foo()) { }` works the same. The odd one out is really a `{ }` block on its own. That would be rather useless if it didn't introduce a new scope. So the apparent inconsistency is due to a misplaced generalization from an exceptional case.

**[edit]**
An alternative view would be to consider an hypothetical, optional keyword:

```
// Not a _conditional_ statement theoretically, but grammatically identical
always()
{
    Foo();
}
```

This unifies the rules, and you wouldn't expect three scope (inside, intermediate,outside) here either.

**[edit 2]** (please don't make this a moving target to answer)

You wonder about lifetime and scopes (two different things) in

```
int i = 0;
for (MyObject o1; i<10; i++) {
   MyObject o2;
}
```

Let's generalize that:

```
MyObject o2; // Outer scope
int i = 0;
for (MyObject o1; i<o1.fooCount(); i++) {
   std::cout << o2.asString();
   MyObject o2;
}
```

Clearly the call to `o2.asString()` refers to the outer `o2`, in all iterations. It's not like the inner `o2` survives the loop iteration. Name lookup doesn't will use names from the outer scope when the names aren't yet defined in the inner scope - and "not yet defined" is a compile-time thing. The repeated construction and destruction of the inner `o2` is a runtime thing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. `{}` introducing a scope is the exceptional and odd case and `if/for/while` is instead the common regular case?

Comment: Yes, do you object to such an interpretation? :) After all, how often do you see a new block introduced by `{}` alone?

Comment: And perhaps more importantly, how often do you see a naked `{ }` for purposes other than to introduce a local scope? In comparison, it's very common to see redundant {} in `if (Bar) { Foo(); }`.

Comment: Not quite correct, the "odd one out" is any block inside another block, whether it's lonely or whether it's introduced by an `if` or a `for` or whatever.

Comment: @MSalters: see edit. If it's one scope, why o2 is destroyed 10 times? If they're two nested scopes why i cannot redefine o1? Why this complication of forbidding the redefinition was considered needed?

Comment: @MSalters: the INNER o2 is destroyed when the scope containing it is exited. But it's the same scope where `o1` is contained in, yet `o1` is not destroyed. Is the flow exiting that scope or not? Why was all this special handling for braces following a `for` considered important? This is the question. What are the use cases that justify this added logical complexity?

Comment: @6502: I assume you mean the cases in which the loop continues (o1 is destroyed directly after inner o2 on the last iteration). If the flow jumps back to the begin of the block, before the inner o2 is defined, the inner o2 from the previous iteration has to be destroyed even though the flow didn't leave the scope - the flow merely jumped around inside the scope.

Comment: @MSalters: whoa. I never realized before that jumping BACK before the definition of an object is ok (thus objects may be destroyed before the end of the scope). I don't use many backward gotos in my C++ code... I would have expected a compile time error like when you jump forward skipping an object definition.

Comment: @MSalters: I've removed the o1/o2 example because indeed it's irrelevant as it can be seen as a single scope with a mere `goto` backward. The question of why the standard didn't chose to just say the body is a statement (thus allowing a nested scope with braces) remains IMO.

Answer (score 5):

Look at it this way:
A pair of braces allows you to hide variables visible inside an **enclosing** pair of braces (or globally):

```
void foo(int n)
{
    // the containing block
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int n = 5;  // allowed: n is visible inside the containing { }
        int i = 5;  // not allowed: i is NOT visible inside the containing { }
    }
}
```

If you think about it this way you realize there are no special rules here.

Answer (score 4):

The brackets (`{}`) deliminate a section of code as a block.  Everything in this block is within it's own local scope:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int a  = 5;
   std::cout<<a<<std::endl      // 5
   {
       int a = 10;
       std::cout<<a<<std::endl  //10
   }
  std::cout<<a<<std::endl       // 5
}
```

But wait, there is something else in that code...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
}
```

This is similar to the structure of a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
{
}
```

The function definition has code outside the `{...}` block too!
in this case, `argc` and `argv` are defined, and *they are local to the scope of the function* just like the definition of `i` in the above `for` loop.

In fact you can generalise the syntax to:

```
definition { expression }
```

Where the entirety of the above is within the scope.
In this case, the 'raw' brackets (`{}`) form the same structure but with an empty definition statement.

edit:
to answer your edit, in:

```
int i = 0;
for (MyObject o1; i<10; i++) {
   MyObject o2;
}
```

the constructor for o2 is looped over for each loop, while the the constructor for o1 isn't.

`for` loop behavior goes as follows (where XXX is the current block being executed:

1. init
   `for(XXX;   ;   ){   }`
2. test loop exp
   `for(   ;XXX;   ){   }`
3. execute block
   `for(   ;   ;   ){XXX}`
4. final operation
   `for(   ;   ;XXX){   }`
5. Back to 2.

Comment: The thing is that `for (int i)` and `{int i}` became the same scope, like it's `int i; int i;` in recent compiler's versions and not `{int i;{int i;}}` like it was before. (Which compiles without errors)

Comment: See my answer, I just posted it. They changed the way `for` works. (And I show there to what they changed it to there)

Comment: Because of that I said to you that you didn't read enough :), this question is about this.

Comment: OK, so all that is wrong is that I didn't discuss why it compiled correctly in previous compiler versions?

Comment: No, the question is why add such rule. Better read it you lazy bastard. :D

Answer (score 2):

The *loop control variables* (`i` and `n` in this case) are considered part of the *for loop*.
And since they are already declared in the loop's *initialization statement*, most attempts (other than re-defining by using nested braces) to re-define them within the loop results in an error!

Comment: It was observed that you _can_ redefine the variables within the loop if you do so within a second set of nested braces. It's not clear to me that _any_ attempt to redefine `n` results in an error, only that _some_ attempts do. (In practice, I suspect you can say "most" rather than just "some.")

Answer (score 2):

As <strike>there is</strike> there was the [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag I would answer from that perspective. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    for (int i = 0, n = 8; i < n; i++) {
        int n = 100;
        printf("%d %d\n", n, a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without issues, see it working at [ideone](http://ideone.com/IWqo0d) (C99 strict mode, 4.8.1).

C standard is clear that both scopes are considered as separate, N1570 6.8.5/p5 (emphasis mine):

> An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of
>   the scope of its enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose
>   scope is a **strict subset** of the scope of the iteration statement.

There is a warning, but only with the `-Wshadow` option, as expected:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow check.c
check.c: In function ‘main’:
check.c:7: warning: declaration of ‘n’ shadows a previous local
check.c:6: warning: shadowed declaration is here
```

Comment: I didn't put a `C` tag. Someone else did.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you why there is just one scope opened by the `for` loop, not a second one due to the braces. But I can say what was given back then as the reason for changing where that single scope is: Locality. Take this kind of pretty standard code:

```
void foo(int n) {
  int s=0;
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    s += global[i];
  }
  // ... more code ...
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    global[i]--;
  }
}
```

Under the old rules, that would have been illegal code, defining `i` twice in the same scope, the function. (In C back then, it was even illegal because you had to declare variables at the beginning of the block.)

That usually meant you’d leave out the declaration in the second loop – and run into problems if the code with the first loop was removed. And whatever you did, you had variables with a long time to live, which as usual makes reasoning about your code harder. (That was before everyone and their brother started to consider ten lines a long function.) Changing `for` to start its own scope before the variable declaration here made code much easier to maintain.

Comment: That locality is important is absolutely clear. In the old days when MS compilers (despite the standardization) were not following this rule my code was using the `#define for if(0)else for` trick to be able to get a local scope to wrap `for` variables. This is however totally irrelevant with the question. Note that the extra special wording for `for/if/while` **removes** locality... and I don't understand why that was considered necessary.

Comment: I don’t see how this removes locality. All I can see is that the scope of the block has been changed to include the “`for (a;b;c)`” part.

Comment: As you can see in the edited question the idea of a single scope encompassing the statement can be used as an explanation for the rules of `for`, but requires you to think in terms of `goto` and also cannot be defended at all for the very same issue in the `if` statement where clearly you cannot think to a single scope (because you can declare the same variable twice) but you cannot use the idea of separate scopes (because you cannot redeclare `x`). The rule forces the outside definition inside the body statement (in case it's a block), forbidding a local declaration with the same name.

Comment: True, `if` is a bit weird in its scoping.

Answer (score -2):

You problem is that the definition part of the for is considered inside the scope of the for.

```
         // V one definition
for(int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++) {
   ...
    // V second definition
   P2d n = ...   <<<--- error here
}
```

Comment: That there is an error is clear. The explanation in the standard is also a bit complex but reasonable. What is not clear is WHY they don't handle the braces normally instead creating a new inner scope... in other words why there is a special rule for that.